# Publish try code in Jenkins before committing

Tags: eclipse, svn, jenkins

I have this development environment with Eclipse as IDE, SVN as SCM and Jenkins as CI server.

Is there a way I could start a Jenkins job from Eclipse and tell Jenkins somehow to take some code from my Eclipse workspace instead of the SVN? Without committing  that code into SVN?

I know how to do the first part (start a job via Mylyn / Builds), but not the second one...

Maybe something like the way TeamCity is integrated into Intellij IDEA and the way they have facilitated gated commits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea using local workspace for a continious integration tool in my opinion. Jenkins runs on a server machine in a standart configuration not in local machine. I think best practice for your scenario is using SVN branches for test committing. Configure a job in jenkins which works with the SVN branch to chechout the code.  Add a svn hook for jenkins to compile after commit. Then integrate the branch to trunk after jenkins successfully build.

Comment: So you would actually work on a branch. Commit the code there. Do the build, run the tests. If all ok integrate to the trunk. How would you do the merge to trunk automatically?

Comment: If there is no conflict between branch and trunk it is easy as just running svn merge commad. You can do this with jenkins by either adding a build step or after build step

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything with Jenkins.
Building code from my local machine in Jenkins is not a good idea though.
If at all you want to achieve this anyway, you can poll specific folder for any change and start building through Jenkins